# "Happy 2nd Birthday" is it correct?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, word-order

What is the rule to follow when we add number to indicate the year in congratulating sentences?
I'm sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. I don't know of any special rules for this, but use words rather than numerals in the sentence: "Happy Second Birthday!" -- Good Luck.

Comment: Please also visit [ell.se]

Comment: Or you could say "Happy birthday number two". That is idiomatic.

Comment: If it's the kid's second birthday then he won't care anyway.  He's just happy to get the cake and presents!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is correct, though *2nd* is an abbreviation. In most cases, you should use *second* instead.

The event is the person's second birthday, and “Happy [event name]” is the usual way to congratulate people, so “Happy second birthday” is correct. Likewise “Happy second anniversary” and “Happy sixty-fifth birthday.”

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers. I found the answer was very satisfying and helpful.